# c# why Convert.ToInt16(num) vs ToInt16(num)?

Tags: c#, .net

what is the difference between `Convert.ToInt16(somenumber)` and `ToInt16(somenumber)` and also vs. `(ToInt16)somenumber`

when do we have to use one over the other?

Comment: what is `ToInt16(somenumber)`?

Comment: Ya ToInt16(somenumber) ??? no idea

Comment: downvoters: please do not explain. (i dont care :)

Comment: not my down votes but I would guess it's one of the follow reasons
There's no ToInt16(somenumber) won't compile unless in a class that defines it's own ToInt16 method which you haven't posted, (ToInt16)somenumber is a cast from somenumber (of a type you didn't specify) to a type named ToInt16. So it's rather hard to actually understand what you're asking. When that's the case questions often get down votes

Comment: This looks like VB.NET-ese to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Convert.ToInt16(somenumber)` Like said by others, Is a method that can be used to convert some types (string for example) to `Int16`.

`ToInt1(somenumber)` I have no idea what this is.

`(ToInt16)somenumber` - No such thing, there is however `(Int16)somenumber` that will cast an object the has an explicit operator overload that return `Int16` (take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93160/Operator-Overloading-with-Implicit-and-Explicit-Ca.aspx))

Comment: sababa jenny I'll be besheket :)

Answer (score 4):

What is the type of `somenumber`?  `Convert.ToXXX` is designed for use with databases and such where you might not know the exact type you're converting from, just that the data is numeric of some sort.

For more typical conversion of a numeric variable to a different size, a cast is better.  But your cast syntax is a little off, it should be `(Int16)somenumber` (no "To").

Finally `ToInt16(somenumber)` looks for a function or delegate field `ToInt16` in the current class (and its base classes), so it's unlikely to compiler properly.

Comment: It's worth noting that if this were VB, you can include static classes as an `Imports` directive, allowing you to access static functions in this manner. I.E., if he had `Imports System.Convert` at the top of the file, you could call `ToInt16(num)`.

Answer (score 4):

[`Convert.Int16()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wxkt09k.aspx) is a method (probably) in `System.Convert`. It has a number of overloads that convert from a type to `Int16`

`.ToInt16()` could be a method defined for a particular class, but most likely you are just referring to the exact same method. Read up on [namespaces](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson06.aspx).

But if you have a class called `Unicorn` and it has a `ToInt16()` method, you obviously will have to use that as there is no overload in `System.Convert` that supports `Unicorn`.

Comment: `Convert` is a class, not a namespace, so you can't bring its members into scope with `using` (although this feature has been requested many times for e.g. `System.Math`).

Comment: @Ben Yeah, I just realized that.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be willing to bet that are exactly the same thing.  Perhaps you meant `Convert.ToInt16(somenumber)` and `Int16.Parse(somenumber).`  In that case the method signature is `Convert.ToInt16(Object somenumber)` and `Int16.Parse(string somenumber)`.

The Convert stuff converts an `object` to a specified type and the Parse stuff Parses a `string` into a specified type.

Answer (score 0):

When converting from a floating point number to an integer there is an important difference:

- `Convert.ToInt16` rounds to the nearest integer (e.g. 1.6 -> 2)
- casting with `(Int16)x` truncates (e.g. 1.6 -> 1)